# Symfony2, fixtures and unit test. Add test data during test in a ManyToMany Relation

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I'm currently facing a big problem. During a unit test, i use fixtures at the beginning of the test to add data into a data base (everything works fine), and I would like to use the same code as the fixture, to add data during the test. Exemple :

Entity Person :

```
class Person {
 
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
 
    [...]
 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Family", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Count(min = "1")
     */
    private $families;
 
    public function __construct() {
        $this->families = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
 
    public function addFamily(Family $family) {
        $this->families[] = $family;
        return $this;
    }
 
    [...]
 
}
```

Entity Family :

```
class Family {
 
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
 
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;
 
    [...]
 
}
```

Fixtures :

```
class Fixture1 implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface {
    /**
     * @var Family[]
     */
    public $families = array();
 
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
 
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $SmithFamily= $this->addFamily("Smith");
        $this->addPerson("Will", "Smith", array($SmithFamily));
    }
 
    public function addFamily($name) {
        $family = new Family();
        $family->setName($name);
        $this->manager->persist($family);
        $this->manager->flush();
        $this->families[$name] = $family;
        return $family;
    }
     
    public function addPerson($firstName, $lastName, array $families = array()) {
        $person = new Person();
        $person->setFirstname($firstName);
        $person->setLastname($lastName);
        foreach ($families as $family) {
            $person->addFamily($family);
        }
         
        $this->manager->persist($person);
        $this->manager->flush();
        return $person;
    }
}
```

Unit Test :

```
class PersonTest extends WebTestCase {
 
    public $fixtures;
 
    protected function setUp() {
        $client = self::createClient();
        $container = $client->getKernel()->getContainer();
        $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
  
        // Purge tables
        $purger = new \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger($em);
        $executor = new \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
        $executor->purge();
  
        // Load fixtures
        $loader = new \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
        $this->fixtures = new Fixture1();
        $this->fixtures->setContainer($container);
        $loader->addFixture($this->fixtures);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
         
        parent::setUp();
    }
 
    public function test1() {
        $this->fixtures->addPerson("James", "Smith", array($this->fixtures->families['Smith']));
        [...]
    }
 
}
```

When I execute the test, i obtain this error :

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: An
>   exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO family (slug, name,
>   created, last_updated_date, deleteddate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
>   params ["smith", "Smith", "2015-01-10 13:59:28", "2015-01-10
>   13:59:28", null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicata du champ 'smith' pour la clef 'UNIQ_A5E6215B989D9B62'

This error says that the "slug" field must be unique. It try to add a new Family, despite of the family already exist. It should just add relation between the new Person (James Smith) and The Family. I don't understand why !
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me take it step by step, here follows a little more than you asked for but I hope it will help you to write cleaner tests as I've seen enough bad ones at my places of work:

First, this is not a unit test, just so you know. It's called a functional test because you are testing the whole system functionality and not a small unit which would be a class.

Second, do not create a new client (createClient call) just for the sake of getting a container. More over usually you don't need more than one client per test case. If you really want to create it in the setUp method then store it in the TestCase field (create a protected field in your TestCase class which you will use for it) and store it in the setUp method so you can use it the test case. That's needed because at some point you will introduce bugs in your test suite by instantiating more than one containers (createClient instantiates a new container each time you call it) and having more than one EntitiManagers for example. Then at some point you will have some entities that belong to one EntityManager and others to another (which is possible to manage but if you don't know how Doctrine works it's better to not face it for you).

Third, you don't need fixture loader in your example at all. Also you don't need to call `purge` here because it is automatically called from executor. This is how your code in setUp could look like:

```
$this->client = self::createClient();
$em = $this->getKernel()->getContainer()->get("doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager");
$executor = new ORMExecutor($em, new ORMPurger());
$executor->execute([new Fixture1()]);

parent::setUp();
```

I think it's much simpler that way.

Also I'm not sure why you need your fixture to be ContainerAware, as you don't use container as far as I can see and in the most cases you don't need to, actually.

Fourth, never store EntityManager in the Fixture instance. It's supposed to get it through `load` method, use it to load everything and forget about it completely.

Try to change your fixture methods to expect manager as an argument instead of using it as a field and call `(new Fixture1)->addPerson($this->client->getKernel()->getContainer()->get("doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"), "James", "Smith", $existingFamily);` from your test method. It looks like you get to use different managers at some point so the second one doesn't know about family yet and as you set up `cascade={persist}` for families in Person it persists it automatically and tries to re-insert.